# Decomposing Double into sign, mantissa and exponent in swift: check my work

Tags: swift, floating-point, double

I've added this extension to Double below to decompose a Double into integer mantissa and exponent in Swift. I've tested it for a number of values, including DBL_MAX and -DBL_MAX. My questions are:
(1) Is there a built in method or function somewhere that already does this? (2) Is this correct, for all environments, with all Doubles? Is there any way it could fail? (3) Is there a way to make it more efficient but still portable?

Thanks for your advice.

```
extension Double {
    func decomp () -> (mantissa:Int64,exponent:Int64) {
        var (a,b) = frexp(self)

        var exponent = Int64(b)

        while floor(a) != a {
            a *= 2
            exponent--
        }
        let mantissa = Int64(floor(a))

        return (mantissa, exponent)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell this should be easy but it doesn't work,

The FloatingPoint protocol, as defined https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/FloatingPoint.swift.gyb , to which the Double struct complies already defines an exponent and a significand variable (on line 207 and 231 respectively).

And the Double struct https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/FloatingPointTypes.swift.gyb , defines the exponent on line 389 and the significand on line 398.

Comment: Thanks -- that's exactly what I needed to know.  I've only just starting porting my stuff to swift the last couple of weeks, and I didn't know that the source code was so easily available.

Answer (score 0):

Staring from Swift 3 there are properties [Double.exponent](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/double/1848471-exponent), [Double.significand](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/double/1847553-significand) and [Double.sign](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/double/1846936-sign).